# Yii2 POST image to model in API without Yii2 Naming convention

Tags: yii2

I'm creating an endpoint for a mobile application to send a image to the server. I'm posting the image with the POSTMAN extension for chrome. The image is in the `$_FILES` variable, and named `image`. How can I load this image into a model, or the `UploadedFile` class? The `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` line does not correctly load the file, as it is not in Yii2's naming convention for forms.

It's currently returning:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Required parameter 'image' is not set."
}
```

**Code**

*models\Image.php*

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class Image extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $image;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        $path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/temp/';
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->image->saveAs($path . $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            die(var_dump($this->errors));
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

*controllers\DefaultController.php*

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use api\modules\v1\models\Image;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use Yii;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $model = new Image();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
            {
                $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
                if ($model->upload()) {
                    // file is uploaded successfully
                    return ['success' => true, 'message' => 'File saved.'];
                }
                else return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'Could not save file.'];
            }
            else return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'Required parameter \'image\' is not set.'];
        }
        else return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'Not a POST request.'];
    }
}
```

**Postman**
[image: Postman POST request]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the name you are using to send the image file. Usually Yii2 uses names for form attributes like "ModelName[attributeName]" and you are sending your image file with the name "image"

There are 2 ways of fixing this:

1. Change the name you use to send your image file to follow the same naming conveniton. However you don't seem to want that.
2. Use `getInstanceByName('image')` method instead of `getInstance($model, 'image')`

Comment: The function you provided in point 2 was exactly what I was after. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem come here 
When you send files via api they are not sent asynchronously. If you check

```
echo '<pre>';
 print_r($_FILES); //returns nothing 
 print_r($_POST["image"]);  //returns something
 echo '</pre>';
die;
```

One reason is that your controller extends`yii\web\controller` which is not used by rest apis, extend `yii\rest\controller`

The other way to go about this is by using javascript  formData when sending the post request

This is a way i handled a previous ajax post of an image probably itll give you a guideline

```
The form
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 
  'multipart/form-data','id'=>'slider_form']]); ?>  //dont forget enctype

 <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>
```

Then on the ajax post

```
 var formData = new FormData($('form#slider_form')[0].files);

$.post(
    href, //serialize Yii2 form 
    {other atributes ,formData:formData}
)

Then on the controller simply access via
$model->file =$_FILES["TblSlider"]; //here this depends on your form attributes check with var_dump($_FILES)
$file_tmp = $_FILES["TblSlider"]["tmp_name"]["file"];
        $file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['TblSlider']['name']["file"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(!empty($model->file)){

            $filename = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:m:s")).".".$file_ext;

            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "../uploads/siteimages/slider/".$filename);
            ///move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, Yii::getAlias("@uploads/siteimages/slider/").$filename);
            $model->image = $filename;
        }
```

I hope this helps